# Jade / JavaScript - Access data being passed to Jade

Tags: javascript, pug

I'm passing a Jade template some data, which is in JSON form, so for example here me outputting the names of all the teams in the Jade template:

```
p Teams:
  br
  -for(var i = 0; i < tournamentData.teams.length; i++) {
    text Team #{i+1}: #{teams[i].name}
    br
  -}
```

This prints all the names of the teams fine. How would I access this data in a JavaScript file? Here I can simply type `#{teams[0].name}` to get the name of the team at 0, but how would I do this in the JavaScript file?

Comment: What do you mean by "the JavaScript file"? The file where you're calling `res.render('file', {tournamentData: json_data});` or another one?

Comment: `file` in this case is a Jade template file, so my code is `res.render('tournament', {tournamentData: json_data});`, how would I also pass this to the JavaScript file? the JS file in this case is a seperate file I am trying to work with for some other purposes

Answer (score 2):

If I properly understood you, you can do it like this:

JS file:

```
function myFn(teams){
    // user teams here
    // for example:

    window.myTeam = teams[0];
}
```

Including file in jade:

```
script(type="text/javascript", onload="myFn(#{JSON.stringify(tournamentData.teams)});", src="urlHere")
```

**Update:**

```
function myFn(bracketData){
    $(function() { $('#tournamentBrackets').bracket({ init: bracketData }); });
}
```

Comment: `$(function() {
 $('#tournamentBrackets').bracket({
  init: bracketData
 });
});` This is my JS file function, so how would I pass it to this function?